# Printing estimates of fixed effects using reghdfe

Tags: regression, stata, fixed, effects

I am using the `reghdfe` command in Stata and I try to include fixed effects by using `absorb()` as well as using  `cluster()`.

1. Is it possible to print or save the estimates of the dummy variables used in `absorb`?
2. For the cluster variables: I have a dataset grouped into 20 different groups. Is it possible to get the regression estimates for the overall regression as well as for the different groups without filtering it first and running it 20 times?

Example dataset:

```
   +---------------------------------------------+
   | state        region          pop   marriage |
   |---------------------------------------------|
1. | Alabama      South     3,893,888     49,018 |
2. | Alaska       West        401,851      5,361 |
3. | Arizona      West      2,718,215     30,223 |
4. | Arkansas     South     2,286,435     26,513 |
5. | California   West     23,667,902    210,864 |
   +---------------------------------------------+
```

I want to run a regression with marriage as the dependent variable and pop as an independent variable. In addition, I want to run the same regression for each state. Is that possible using the `cluster()` command or do I have to run it separately for each state?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `savefe` option to capture the estimated fixed effects:

```
sysuse auto
reghdfe price weight length, absorb(rep78) // basic useage
reghdfe price weight length, absorb(rep78, savefe) // saves with '__hdfe' prefix
```

Then you can plot these `__hdfe*` parameters however you like.

Items you can clarify to get a better answer:

1. Please edit the question to provide information about how you are plotting the estimates. Without that information I can't provide any specifics.
2. It's a little unclear what you want to do with the cluster variables.

Comment: Thank you! For the fixed effects, that was exactly what I was searching for! For the cluster variables: I have a dataset grouped into 20 different groups. Is it possible to get the regression estimates for the overall regression as well as for the different groups without filtering it first and running it 20 times?

Comment: Still a bit unclear what you’re after. If you read: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info you’ll get a better sense of the sort of information that it helps to put into a question.

Comment: Again, thanks! I added an example in my question above. I hope, it helps to understand my problem.

Comment: Please add things like the actual code you’re using and more detail on what you are trying to do.